# Start & end time in a bar chart PowerBI & DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I work in production where we measure the time use of different machines. Basically I want to show my colleagues with a bar chart in PowerBI when most people start using the machine and when most people are done with the machine (showed in full hours, for example 7, 10, 16).

I have 2 column (start time & end time) that are in time format (16:30:00) that I've changed to whole numbers (Start time as number) and a end time as number that can't be seen in picture due to broad sheet. See below

[image]
Formula: `Start time as number = HOUR(sheet1[Start time])`

The problem I have occurred is when I take start time and end time in same table it shows exactly the same values? But if I make a table with start and a different with end, it shows the correct result. See below pictures:

[image: Merging the values from start and end time]

Above is the merge of Start and End time but it should look like below

[image: Left is start time and right is end time]

The left table above is start time and right table is end time of machine.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** When I try formula from Mik

[image]

**EDIT** Picture of my situation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think it's correct now! Will try on my main data.

Comment: Create a time table and column for time scale in your graph and then use a TREATAS()

Comment: Trying to figure it out how to use that formula through Youtube. `COUNT ( [timetable], TREATAS( { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}, [Start time as number])` wont work.

Comment: It's very close to the idea, but I think it can be easer like in my answer.

Comment: I altered the answer, so you can test it for now. You do not need to establish relations. Just add the table for hour (Ox) scale

Comment: Hi, did you try my last update?

Comment: Hi, where should I generate this Ox Scale? When I try inside my fact table it just says "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected." When make a new DIM table with Hours I don't know how to connect it.

Comment: Did you create a table with this expression `Hours = GENERATESERIES(0,23,1)`? And did you add the scale from a `Hours [Value]` column? And you don't need to link tables

Comment: See my latest edit, picture of my current situation.

Comment: The second is correct use it for scale, and make correction for the `SELECTEDVALUE(tableName[ColumnName])`

Comment: I think it's correct now, will try at my main data!

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much once again Mik! You really know what you are doing :D Have a nice day!

Comment: Great, Thank you for a feedback, see you around )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a table for Ox scale with

```
Hours = GENERATESERIES(0,23,1)
```

This is a measure for start ( for end is the same just change the column name)

```
start = 
    COUNTROWS(
         FILTER(
             'sheet1'
             ,HOUR(sheet1[Start time])
                   =SELECTEDVALUE(Hours[Value])
         )
    )


end = 
    COUNTROWS(
         FILTER(
             'sheet1'
             ,HOUR(sheet1[End time])
                   =SELECTEDVALUE(Hours[Value])
         )
    )
```

Comment: I doesn't work :/ I get nonsense result. Says that the machines have only started 7 and 16. When I know there is all the different times.

Comment: do you have any active filters or slicers?

Comment: Slicers for all the different machines. So it goes haywire when i try to filter on a machine.

Comment: Starting to think it has something to do with my relations. Right now I got a table with 0-24 (Time). But not sure where to connect it to? Depends on what I connect it to (either Start time or end time), the data changes. How could I counter this?

Comment: See above for picture when I tried your formula.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G_mFwZMLO8FvInZjSkNmKfQAcAnhLhi4IngKykFULxo/edit?usp=sharing) Here is a spreadsheet with the data.

Comment: Ok, I'll look through within today

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the relationship between my data table and how to get a hour table connected. Don't know how to solve it, doesn't really have any joint keys.

Comment: Hello Fraita. If you want to create a time table, first decide the cardinality. It will be minutes or hours. Because It will filter your Fact table [Start Time] and [End Time] Columns. It depends on how you want it. you can create 2 time tables in hour using generate series function. (Parameters: Start(0),Finish(23),Step(1)) then after the column is formed, change the format to time. After creating 2 such dim time tables, build a one - Many relationship with your fact table. One will be [Time] - [Start time]... The other [Time] - [End time]. Try and fail is a good tactics in BI to learn more.

Comment: Hi Ozan, 

tried to make 2 dim tables with 0-23 and tried to connect it to my start time as number and end time as number but it doesnt work :/ Even tried to generate a seires of 0-23 in my fact table, didnt work because to many rows compared to 0-23. Can you explain a bit further how to counter this? Thanks!

Comment: I can't change the generated series to Hour format (cardinality), it just gives me 00:00:00